# How to extract Unicode characters like &\#1071; for "Я" from a quill editor's INNERHTML?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, quill

I'm pulling Russian text from a database to feed it into a Quill editor, to present this text to a user text for editing. Each letter of the text is encoded (like `&\#1071;` for "Я"). My HTML header defines `CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`, so this displays correctly.

Once my user finished editing, I am then reading the INNERHTML of my quill editor to write it back into my database:

```
<php
    echo "var tmpVar = document.getElementById(\"LD_LOC\").innerHTML;";
?>
```

However, none the original coding (like `&\#1071;`) survives this, but all letters are replaced by some unreadable special characters (not even "Я").

Is (How is) it possible to extract coded text from my quill editor's INNERHTML? Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you _sure_ 8859-1 is correct?

Comment: Thank you, jdv. In the end, it turned out that I should have used UTF-8, which @martinstoeckli was kind enough to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get much better results, when you switch to UTF-8 for the whole site, I used quill myself with UTF-8 and it even works with 4 byte emojis. The whole site means, the page encoding, the page header and if available the database access. I wrote a [small article](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8) about this topic, with more in-depth explanations.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem. I switched my php page to `CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` and then opened my ADODB connection specifying the character set: `$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection", NULL, CP_UTF-8);`.